# Tkinter matplotlib - clear canvas and load second figure

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I need plot only last image on the `Tkinter` canvas.
I did lot of research here and tried multiple things but I am not successful. Somehow my code add the images to the bottom of original image.
I have tried `canvas.destroy()`, `canvas.clear()`, `fig.clf()`, `fig.clear()`, `ax1.cla()` etc but nothing worked for me.
What I want is clear the first image of REGION = 'NORTH AMERICA' and replace it with image of REGION = 'LATAM' data.
Instead this code is adding them to the bottom

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

root=tk.Tk()

# ----------- REGION 1 PLOT -------------
data = {'SALES_MONTH':['01-Jan-21','01-Jan-21','01-Feb-21','01-Feb-21','01-Mar-21','01-Mar-21','01-Apr-21','01-Apr-21','01-May-21','01-May-21','01-Jan-21','01-Jan-21','01-Jan-21','01-Feb-21','01-Feb-21','01-Feb-21','01-Mar-21','01-Mar-21','01-Mar-21','01-Apr-21','01-Apr-21','01-Apr-21','01-May-21','01-May-21','01-May-21'],
'REGION':['NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM'],
'COUNTRY':['USA','CANADA','USA','CANADA','USA','CANADA','USA','CANADA','USA','CANADA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA'],
'QUANTITY':['1000','400','1000','400','1000','400','1000','400','1000','400','700','450','150','700','450','150','700','450','150','700','450','150','700','450','150']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())

df = df[df['REGION']== 'NORTH AMERICA']

df = df[['SALES_MONTH', 'QUANTITY']]
df = df.groupby(['SALES_MONTH'], as_index=False)['QUANTITY'].sum()

print(df.head())
df['SALES_MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SALES_MONTH'])
df = df.set_index('SALES_MONTH').asfreq('MS')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.sort_values('SALES_MONTH',ascending=True)
print(df.head())

from statsmodels.tsa.filters.hp_filter import hpfilter
qtycycle , qtytrend = hpfilter(df['QUANTITY'], lamb=129600)
df['SALES_TREND'] = qtytrend
df['SALES_CYCLE'] = qtycycle
print(df.head())

x = df.index.to_numpy()
y = df['QUANTITY'].to_numpy()
y1 = df['SALES_TREND'].to_numpy()
y2 = df['SALES_CYCLE'].to_numpy()

date_form = DateFormatter("%y-%m")

fig = Figure(figsize=(16,7),dpi=100)
fig.tight_layout()

fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=0.6)
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y1)
ax3.plot(x,y2)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax1.set_title('Sales Quantity')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax2.set_title('Sales Trend')
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax3.set_title('Sales Cycle')

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = tk.TOP,fill = tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# ----------- REGION 2 PLOT -------------
data = {'SALES_MONTH':['01-Jan-21','01-Jan-21','01-Feb-21','01-Feb-21','01-Mar-21','01-Mar-21','01-Apr-21','01-Apr-21','01-May-21','01-May-21','01-Jan-21','01-Jan-21','01-Jan-21','01-Feb-21','01-Feb-21','01-Feb-21','01-Mar-21','01-Mar-21','01-Mar-21','01-Apr-21','01-Apr-21','01-Apr-21','01-May-21','01-May-21','01-May-21'],
'REGION':['NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','NORTH AMERICA','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM','LATAM'],
'COUNTRY':['USA','CANADA','USA','CANADA','USA','CANADA','USA','CANADA','USA','CANADA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA','MEXICO','COSTA RICA','COLOMBIA'],
'QUANTITY':['1000','400','1000','400','1000','400','1000','400','1000','400','700','450','150','700','450','150','700','450','150','700','450','150','700','450','150']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())

df = df[df['REGION']== 'LATAM']

df = df[['SALES_MONTH', 'QUANTITY']]
df = df.groupby(['SALES_MONTH'], as_index=False)['QUANTITY'].sum()

print(df.head())
df['SALES_MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SALES_MONTH'])
df = df.set_index('SALES_MONTH').asfreq('MS')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.sort_values('SALES_MONTH',ascending=True)
print(df.head())

from statsmodels.tsa.filters.hp_filter import hpfilter
qtycycle , qtytrend = hpfilter(df['QUANTITY'], lamb=129600)
df['SALES_TREND'] = qtytrend
df['SALES_CYCLE'] = qtycycle
print(df.head())

x = df.index.to_numpy()
y = df['QUANTITY'].to_numpy()
y1 = df['SALES_TREND'].to_numpy()
y2 = df['SALES_CYCLE'].to_numpy()

date_form = DateFormatter("%y-%m")

fig = Figure(figsize=(16,7),dpi=100)
fig.tight_layout()

fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=0.6)
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y1)
ax3.plot(x,y2)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax1.set_title('Sales Quantity')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax2.set_title('Sales Trend')
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax3.set_title('Sales Cycle')

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = tk.TOP,fill = tk.BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```